# Selecting zip codes without using lasso tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, select-by-location

I'm new to ArcGIS Desktop.

I have a layer representing US zip codes and another layer of data points. I need to select all the data points within every zip code and find out the min-max value of the data points within that zip code. Currently, I've been selecting the zip code through the lasso tool and then performing a select by location but this is very time-consuming.

Is there any other way that I could possibly select all the data points zip code by zip code without having to use the lasso tool?

Answer (score 4):

You will want to do a select by location, based on the zip codes you want. For example, if you only want 10 zip codes, you will select those 10 zip codes (manual selection, or select by attributes), and then select by location with your data points. With the select by location you will use the selected zip codes as a selection criteria.

Comment: This is pretty much one solution given at the other question, but it doesn't solve what is apparently not entirely clear from the asker's wording and all the discussion about selection *which is not actually necessary*.  The goal is a table with the min/max values for *each* zip code individually, and to generate this table with as few steps as possible (ie, not selecting/calculating them one by one).

Comment: A spatial join will intersect the zip code polygons, and put the attribute of the zip code in the point layer attribute table. With the attributes in the point layer, you can then perform SQL queries as needed, without any manual selections.